# Hover/Zoom on Lightbox gallery

Tags: gallery

Is there a way to hover/zoom on the larger image in a lightbox gallery. I am using Lightbox Gallery Manager from Raygun and have several galleries on a page. Once the lightbox gallery is opened, I want to be able to zoom in on parts of the image to see more detail. Here is the webpage that I am building http://tandcupholstery.com/customer-restorations/. I have the lightbox galleries working, but once the larger image opens I want to be able to zoom in.

Comment: This seems more Javascript/Lightbox than specifically WordPress to me.

Answer (score 0):

Betty,

It doesn't look like the plugin you are using supports zooming in an image. This means that you would have to modify the plugin, or add another plugin that would modify the images that are being loaded by the lightbox plugin.

Here's a link to a pretty neat jquery plugin to zooming images:

[Jquery Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

However, you will need access to your theme files and some basic jquery skills to make the necessary changes.